# Granting role doesn't stick

Tags: oracle

I've created a user with a default tablespace.  I've granted create session to that user and then added them to a role GRANT xxxx_role TO myuser;

However when I run SELECT * FROM USER_ROLE_PRIVS, there are no rows of data, meaning the user isn't assigned to any roles.  It says that the grant succeeded.  What am I doing wrong? I've done this as a SYSTEM user which should have carte blanche permissions.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Are you saying that you have a row in `user_role_privs` where the `username` is populated but `granted_role` is `null`?  That sounds very, very odd.

Comment: No, I'm saying there are no rows at all for this user in USER_ROLE_PRIVS

Comment: `user_role_privs` shows roles granted to the current user.  `dba_role_privs` shows roles granted to all users.  Unless you are logging in as `myuser` after running the grant as `system` in order to query `user_role_privs`, you should be querying `dba_role_privs'.

Answer (score 2):

`user_role_privs` shows roles granted to the current user.  `dba_role_privs` shows roles granted to all users.  You probably want to be querying `dba_role_privs`.

If you are logged in as `system` and do the grant, you should see a row in `dba_role_privs` for `myuser`.  You won't see rows in `user_role_privs` for any user other than `system`.  If you log in as `myuser` after the grant is done, you will see a row in `user_role_privs`.